# What colors of lightsaber crystals are there (and where can I get them)?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Seeing this question [How do I get a Magenta Lightsaber Crystal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46369/how-do-i-get-a-magenta-lightsaber-crystal), I see that there are more lightsaber colors than I thought.

I know there are:

- Red
- Yellow
- Purple
- Green
- Blue
- Yellow + Dark center (preorder)

What else is there?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Standard

Green quality items. Requires low-level Artifice to craft (items at level 7 and above); found in standard weapons and as drops/rewards.

- **Red**
- **Blue**
- **Green**
- **Yellow**

---

## Prototype

Blue quality items.

- All the above
- **Orange** (first drops are level 31; artifice-craftable beginning with level 47)

---

## Artifact

Purple quality items.

#### Artifice 400

- All the above (Orange level 50 schematics drop from the Primal Destroyer world boss on Belsavis)
- **Magenta**, AKA "Light Red" ([must be crafted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/46369/6066))

#### Artifice 500

- **White-Purple-Blue** (added with Patch 3.0; not to be confused with White-Blue-Purple)
- **White-Yellow-Orange** (added with Patch 3.0)

---

## Operations Drops

The PvE versions drop from Explosive Conflict, Terror from Beyond, and Scum and Villainy.  They can be reverse engineered to learn the crafting schematic.  The PvP versions come directly from the PvP Items vendor and cannot be learned via RE.

- **Black-Orange**
- **Black-Purple**
- **Black-Red**
- **Black-Blue**
- **Cyan**, AKA "Light Blue" (PvP schematic drops from Grade 6 PvP crafting boxes)
- **Purple** (PvP schematic drops from Grade 6 PvP crafting boxes)

---

## Cartel Pack Crystals

These crystals can be sold on the GTN or traded/mailed after a lockout period.  There were no crystals in Shipment 4.

#### Shipment 1: Cartel Packs

- **White** (all packs except Black Market)
- **Pink-Purple** (Black Market and Crime Lord's packs)
- **Cyan-Blue** (Blockade Runner's pack)
- **Orange-Red** (Skip Tracer's pack)
- **Lime-Green** (Space Pirate's pack)

#### Shipment 2: Contraband Packs

- **White-Black** (all packs except Regulator's)
- **Derelict-Purple** (Regulator's and Enforcer's packs)
- **Silver-Blue** (Vice Commandant's pack)
- **Mint-Green** (Archon's pack)
- **Copper** (Supreme Mogul's pack)

#### Shipment 3: Bounty Packs

- **Hot Orange** (all packs except Contractor's)
- **Blood Red** (Contractor's and Freelancer's packs)
- **Blue Core** (Pursuer's pack)
- **Charred Orange** (Tracker's pack)
- **Yellow Blue** (Opportunist's pack)

#### Nightlife Packs

- **Pink Magenta** (Star Cluster Nightlife Pack)
- **Yellow Core** (Club Vertica Nightlife Pack)

#### Shipment 5: Stronghold Packs

- **Gold Core** (all packs except Builder's)
- **Blue Outline** (Builder's and Gatekeeper's packs)
- **Pink Core** (Constable's pack)
- **Sea Green** (Seneschal's pack)
- **Purple Outline** (Architect's Pack)

#### Shipment 6: Shadow Packs

- **Black-Pink** (all packs except Initiate's)
- **Purple-Black** (Initiate's and Pilgrim's packs)
- **White-Blue-Purple** (Acolyte's pack)
- **Pink-Red** (Apprentice's pack)
- **Pink-Yellow** (Master's pack)

#### Shipment 7: Explorer Packs

- **Green Empeth** (all packs except Core Worlds)
- **Blue-Cyan-Indigo** (Core Worlds and Deep Core packs)

---

## Cartel Market Crystals

These are sold directly from the Cartel Market and do not appear in the gambling packs.

- **Orange-Yellow**
- **Green Core**

---

## Special

- **White** (world boss drop during beta; sold on the fleets prior to Patch 1.2)
- **Black-Green** (Rakghoul Outbreak and Rakghoul Resurgence event rewards)
- **Black-Silver Striated** (Season 4 [low-tier group and mid-tier solo](http://www.swtor.com/info/news/blog/20150318) Ranked PvP reward)

---

## Discontinued

These are still in the game but can no longer be acquired if you don't have them already.

- **Black-Yellow** (for pre-ordering the game)
- **Razer Black/Green** (for buying a Razer SWTOR peripheral.  This is a different color than the standard Black/Green; see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8O4P.jpg))
- **Black-Purple Striated** ([March 2015 Subscriber reward](http://www.swtor.com/info/news/news-article/20150226))

#### Ranked PvP Rewards

- **Furious Red-Yellow** (Season 3 reward, any rating)
- **Black-Blue Striated** (Season 4 mid-tier reward)

---

## Unavailable

These are part of the game assets but have not been made generally available.

- **Black-Cyan**
- **Black-White** (the inverse of White-Black)

Comment: This was just a quick search. :) Feel free to add what I missed, or post your own list.

Comment: There's also the Green/Black from buying a Razor peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

- Red
- Blue
- Green
- Yellow
- Orange
- Purple
- White (world boss drop)
- Magenta (mentioned in patch notes, "Added rare Magenta Adegan color crystal schematics for Artifice")
- Yellow/Black (Pre-Order Crystal)

PVP Rewards, insanely hard to get:

- Red/Black
- Blue/Black
- Purple/Black
- Orange/Black