# How do I obtain a white lightsaber crystal?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What colors of lightsaber are there (and where can I get them)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46668/what-colors-of-lightsaber-are-there-and-where-can-i-get-them)

Is there any way to get the white lightsaber crystal? I have seen people with them running around, and they said it was obtained by drops, but they won't say what dropped it. I would like to have one for my saber. Is there any way to get one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What colors of lightsaber are there (and where can I get them)?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/46668/6066)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before Patch 1.2, you could buy them for 1 to 2.5 million credits on the Fleet. The vendor for the Imperial version, Geologist Pajro, was in the southwest section.  The Republic version was [Geologist Breshin](http://db.darthhater.com/npcs/34850/geologist_breshin/).

Currently only people who bought them prior to Patch 1.2 have them; they were bind on pickup.

(In beta, they were a drop from a world boss.)

Comment: Note that this vendor is going away with the 1.2 patch.

Answer (score 0):

Since Patch 1.5, white crystals can be obtained via random Cartel Pack drops.  They are Bind on Equip and can be sold on the GTN.